# платное отключение рекламы в приложении

Tags: android

Есть приложение в маркете где полноэкранная реклама. Уже несколько людей пишут как можно отключить рекламу в приложении, без отключения интернета. Собственно хочу понять как это можно реализовать? Код рекламы у меня в самом Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы сделать платное отключение рекламы, нужно реализовать оплату с помощью In-app платежей, и не показывать рекламу, если это было оплачено.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html#api

Comment: спасибо. буду смотреть